# By postman testing is there anyway to call after test for cleanup

Tags: testing, postman-newman

In Junit test there is @After for the clenaup. Is there any similar way for the postman testing? If yes, how it should be done? Pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it. I can simpley do it after the test as the last test for the clenaup

```
pm.test("Clean up after test", function () {
    // Add your cleanup code here
});
```